# What may be causing the error "Unhandled promise rejection" starting in Safari 16.3

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

In looking through the logs I started seeing website errors `Unhandled promise rejection: Not implemented on this platform` and Unhandled promise rejection:  starting Jan 24th which corresponds to Safari 16.3 release. My question is what changed and how to fix it. Does this mean to just implement [handlerejection events?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) ?

Reference:

> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213600 Safari 16.3 Release notes for
> January 23, 2023
>
> WebKit Available for: macOS Big Sur and macOS Monterey Impact:
> Processing maliciously crafted web content may lead to arbitrary code
> execution Description: The issue was addressed with improved checks.
> WebKit Bugzilla: 245464
>
> WebKit Available for: macOS Big Sur and macOS Monterey Impact:
> Processing maliciously crafted web content may lead to arbitrary code
> execution Description: The issue was addressed with improved memory
> handling. WebKit Bugzilla: 248268

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this too, and found this github issue: https://github.com/WordPress/openverse/issues/524

That points to it possibly being a LastPass extension.

As for implementing unhandled rejection event, it can depend. Mostly when you have an error thrown and not caught, you want to catch it closer to where its thrown. The global unhandled rejection listener on the window is at the highest level where you lose context to best handle any errors.

In this case, the error is likely happening from an extension. It is the extensions responsibility to catch this error before it gets to that point.

Try running Safari without extensions and see if it keeps happening.